# What is the correct way to deep clone PDPage?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working with PDFBOX v2, I'm trying to clone the first PDPage of a PDDocument for keep it as template for new PDPages. That first page, has some acroform fields that I need fill.

I tried some methods but anyone makes I want to achieve.

1) Copy the first page content and add it to the document when I need a new page. That copy the page but the acroform field are linked with other pages fields, and  if I modify field value from the first page, that shows in the other pages.

```java
//Save in variable first page content
COSDictionary pageContent = (COSDictionary)doc.getPage(0).getCOSObject();
...

//when i need insert new page
doc.addPage(new PDPage(pageContent));
```

2) Clone the first page content and then add to the document like the first method. That copy the page but no field is copied :/

```java
PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(doc);
COSDictionary pageContent = (COSDictionary)cloner.cloneForNewDocument(doc.getPage(0).getCOSObject());

...

//when i need insert new page
doc.addPage(new PDPage(pageContent));
```

Then, what is the correct way to make a deep copy of a PDPage getting acroform fields independent from the first page?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO the simplest way would be to delete all pages except the first one, and then to save that. The problem is that Acroform is both document level (fields) and page level (annotations).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr there is any way to rename cloned fields?

Comment: You shouldn't use the PDFCloneUtility class at all, see its javadoc. The name of a field can be set with `setPartialName()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I tried with annotations and i dont like this, the final pdf user can modify it :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What did you try and what effect was not wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!

1) Start with an empty pdf template, only has 1 page. Open template document, fill common data and save as byte[] in memory.

```java
PDDocument templatedoc = PDDocument.load(new File(path));           
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = templatedoc.getDocumentCatalog();           

PDAcroFrom acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm());

... fill acroForm common data of all pages ...

ByteArrayOutputStream basicTemplate = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
templatedoc.save(basicTemplate);

byte[] filledBasicTemplate = basicTemplate.toByteArray();
```

2) Generate new document for each needed page.

```java
List<PDDocument> documents = new ArrayList<PDDocument>();
PDDocument activeDoc;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  activeDoc = PDDocument.load(filledBasicTemplate);
  documents.add(activeDoc);

  ... fill acroform or you need in each page ...

}
```

3) Import all new document first pages into final document and save final document.

```java
PDDocument finalDoc = new PDDocument();

for(PDDocument currentDoc : documents) {
   ... fill common things like page numbers ...
   finalDoc.importPage(currentDoc.getPage(0));
}

finalDoc.save(new File(path));


... close all documents after save the final document ...
```

It maybe not be the most optimized code, but it works.

Comment: That's a bit confusing; make sure that the widgets that you get when starting from AcroForm are the same one in your pages, and that the widget annotations also point back to the page of the final document. (call `annotation.setPage()`)