# Iterative cloning of a Page with PDFBox and writing each of them differently

Tags: java, heap-memory, clone, pdfbox

I want to iterate over a list of input data. For every input (which also has input objects to write on a template) I want to clone the template and write said input.

Some how the pages I have cloned are written overlaid with every input given in the whole list.

I tried to deepcopy the COSDictonary or generate the COSDictonary for every iteration seperatly.

```
 PDDocument templateDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
    templateDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    PDDocument finalDocument = new PDDocument();

    if (templateDocument != null) {
        PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(templateDocument);
        PDPage originalPage = templateDocument.getPage(0);
        int count=0;
        //inputs is an ArrayList of Arraylists
        for (List<Input> input : inputs) {
            //fieldEnrichment() maps the input data with the loaded fields from a config file
            fieldEnrichment(fields, input);
            COSDictionary pageDictionary = (COSDictionary) cloner.cloneForNewDocument(originalPage)
            PDPage page = new PDPage(pageDictionary);
            finalDocument.addPage(page);
            //writeFieldsIntoLastPage() creates a contentStream and writes the input into the page
            writeFieldsIntoLastPage(finalDocument, fields);
            clearFieldsFromInput(fields);
            count++;
        }

        finalDocument.save(new File("result/data/" + "Test_" + splitPathToName(path)));
        finalDocument.close();

    }

}
```

[What is the correct way to deep clone PDPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571857/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deep-clone-pdpage) his solution solved the problem by creating a new pdf file for every page, but since wanting to generate +10000 pages a Memory issue occurs.

Has somebody an idea how to use the templatePage of the originalDoc "unwritten" for every loop adding it directly into the finalDocument?

Comment: You use `cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(templateDocument)`, so `cloner` clones _into_ your `templateDocument`. This probably is wrong, your eventual target is `finalDocument` after all. Furthermore, you often mention _fields_ in your code. Do you mean **AcroForm** fields or just some abstract field notion?

Comment: `PDFCloneUtility` will be removed from public in 3.0. You can create/save a PDF file in memory too.